# Use one JOIN more times as more columns

Tags: sql, join

I have four tables as follows (there is a lot more, actually, I omitted the unimportant ones for this question):

[image]

One product can have up to 5 groups associated using the junction table. I need to `JOIN` the tables and print all of the 5 groups and 5 areas and the one associated product as 11 columns.

Expected result (for instance):

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Product | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------|
|    1    |    2    |    1    |   NULL  |   NULL  |   NULL  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+

          +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
          | Area 1  | Area 2  | Area 3  | Area 4  | Area 5  |
          +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------|
          |    5    |    8    |   NULL  |   NULL  |   NULL  |
          +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I have the following SQL query:
`

```
Select p.id, a1.area_id as 'Area 1', a2.area_id as 'Area 2', a3.area_id as 'Area 3', a4.area_id as 'Area 4', a5.area_id as 'Area 5', g1.group_id as 'Group 1', g2.group_id as 'Group 2', g3.group_id as 'Group 3', g4.group_id as 'Group 4', g5.group_id as 'Group 5'
From Product p
Inner Join group_product_junction j on p.product_id = j.product_id
Inner Join Group g1 on j.group_id = g1.group_id
Inner Join Group g2 on j.group_id = g2.group_id
Inner Join Group g3 on j.group_id = g3.group_id
Inner Join Group g4 on j.group_id = g4.group_id
Inner Join Group g5 on j.group_id = g5.group_id
Inner Join Area a1 a on g1.area_id = a1.area_id
Inner Join Area a2 a on g2.area_id = a2.area_id
Inner Join Area a3 a on g3.area_id = a3.area_id
Inner Join Area a4 a on g4.area_id = a4.area_id
Inner Join Area a5 a on g5.area_id = a5.area_id
```

`

But this gives me the same values for all columns. I guess I'm missing a `WHERE` clause or something, but I just can't figure out what it should look like.

Comment: Have you tried using left joins?

Comment: I have, that gives me the same result as with the Inner joins.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @jWeaver, that looks much better.

Comment: Of course you will see the same results for the group values, there is no difference between any of your joins. You might want an additional join condition in the ON clause (maybe `grouptype = 1` or something in this essence).
What are the additional columns on your table you could use ?
By the way, which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: It seems, the result looks like a pivot table. Does your database supports pivot transformations?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server.

Comment: It should support, of course.

Comment: All right, I'll try to wrap my head aroung pivots, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve your requirement, you have to create a notion of *order* in the groups that are linked to a given product. This is because you ultimately will select up to five groups (and areas) in a particular order (i.e. group *1*, group *2*, group *3*, etc.), for a given product.

An order for an entire result-set can be achieved using the `order by` clause, but that's not sufficient here, because we need an order *for each product independently*. This is why partition functions exist; to allow operating on subgroups of a result-set, without aggregating the entire group into one record in the process (which is what `group by` would do).

So, what we can do is join each product record with all of its groups (which, as you indicated, can number no more than five per product) and then run the partition function [`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to partition by product. This will allow us to create a new column that will label each group of each product with a distinct number in that product's set of groups. We will then be able to `left join` five times with the labelled intermediate table, filtering for labels 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 respectively, thus getting each group in its own join. It's then a simple matter of traversing the table links through the group table and then the area table to get all the information we need to build the desired result-set.

```
create table FArea (area_id int primary key);
create table FGroup (group_id int primary key, area_id int references FArea(area_id));
create table FProduct (product_id int primary key);
create table Fgroup_product_junction (group_id int references FGroup(group_id), product_id int references FProduct(product_id));

-- product 1
insert into FProduct (product_id) values (1);
insert into FArea (area_id) values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
insert into FGroup (group_id,area_id) values (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5);
insert into Fgroup_product_junction (group_id,product_id) values (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1), (5,1);

-- product 2
insert into FProduct (product_id) values (2);
insert into FArea (area_id) values (6), (7), (8);
insert into FGroup (group_id,area_id) values (6,6), (7,7), (8,8);
insert into Fgroup_product_junction (group_id,product_id) values (6,2), (7,2), (8,2);

select * from FArea;
select * from FGroup;
select * from FProduct;
select * from Fgroup_product_junction;

with t_pg as (
    select
        p.product_id,
        j.group_id,
        row_number() over (partition by p.product_id order by j.group_id) num
    from
        FProduct p
        inner join Fgroup_product_junction j on j.product_id=p.product_id
)
select
    p.product_id "Product",
    g1.group_id "Group 1",
    g2.group_id "Group 2",
    g3.group_id "Group 3",
    g4.group_id "Group 4",
    g5.group_id "Group 5",
    a1.area_id "Area 1",
    a2.area_id "Area 2",
    a3.area_id "Area 3",
    a4.area_id "Area 4",
    a5.area_id "Area 5"
from
    FProduct p
    left join t_pg j1 on j1.product_id=p.product_id and j1.num=1 left join FGroup g1 on g1.group_id=j1.group_id left join FArea a1 on a1.area_id=g1.area_id
    left join t_pg j2 on j2.product_id=p.product_id and j2.num=2 left join FGroup g2 on g2.group_id=j2.group_id left join FArea a2 on a2.area_id=g2.area_id
    left join t_pg j3 on j3.product_id=p.product_id and j3.num=3 left join FGroup g3 on g3.group_id=j3.group_id left join FArea a3 on a3.area_id=g3.area_id
    left join t_pg j4 on j4.product_id=p.product_id and j4.num=4 left join FGroup g4 on g4.group_id=j4.group_id left join FArea a4 on a4.area_id=g4.area_id
    left join t_pg j5 on j5.product_id=p.product_id and j5.num=5 left join FGroup g5 on g5.group_id=j5.group_id left join FArea a5 on a5.area_id=g5.area_id
;
```

[image: results]

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

```
 select 
  product_id , 
    case when row_id = 1 then group_id end as Group1,
    case when row_id = 2 then group_id end as Group2,
    case when row_id = 3 then group_id end as Group3,
    case when row_id = 4 then group_id end as Group4,
    case when row_id = 5 then group_id end as Group5,
    case when row_id = 1 then area_id end as Area1,
    case when row_id = 2 then area_id end as Area2,
    case when row_id = 3 then area_id end as Area3,
    case when row_id = 4 then area_id end as Area4,
    case when row_id = 5 then area_id end as Area5
from 
(
  Select 
    row_number() over (partition by p.product_id order by p.product_id,j.group_id) row_id,
    p.product_id,
    g.group_id,
    g.area_id
  From Product p
  left Join group_product_junction j on p.product_id = j.product_id
  Left Join groups g on  g.group_id = j.group_id
 ) T
```

Here is [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d17e05/16)

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my part when editing the query for this question, the groups are actually correct (edited my OP now).

Comment: See the updated answer. It generates output as you want.